# Consultar em duas tabelas simultaneamente com dois parâmetros diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Olá, boa noite!

Estou criando uma agenda de eventos por horário, em locais diferentes. Então preciso que, antes mesmo de agendar o evento, mostre quais os locais estão disponíveis, após os locais disponíveis, preciso exibir os horários disponíveis.

Já tentei procurar aqui e em diversos outros locais, mas não encontrei uma solução que atende.

Tenho 5 tabelas com 28 horários idênticos, mas com locais diferentes.

Basicamente, usando Ajax, consigo encontrar o local e horários disponíveis, mas como posso fazer para encontrar por dias diferentes?

**Declaração da Data** 
O *returnSalas();* apenas retorna quais as salas têm cadastradas no BD

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="data">Data:</label>
   <input type="date" name="data" id="data" onchange="returnSalas();" placeholder="Data" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Retorno das salas no BD**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="sala_de_aula">Sala:</label>
    <select name ="sala_de_aula" id="sala_de_aula" class="form-control" onchange="returnHorariosDisp();">
        <?php
           if (!isset($_GET['DataSelecionada'])) {
        ?>
             <option disabled selected>Informe a data Primeiro</option>
        <?php
              }
        ?>
     </select>
</div>
```

**O papel do Ajax é retornar as salas no trecho acima**
*returnHorariosDisp();* = Buscar os horários disponíveis desta sala e retornar no próximo trecho:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
   <label for="horario_entrada">Horário de Entrada</label>
   <select name="horario_entrada" id="horario_entrada" class="form-control">
      <?php
         if (!isset($_GET['SalaSelecionada'])) {
      ?>
          <option disabled selected>Selecione a sala de aula</option>
      <?php
            }
      ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

O banco de dados têm as seguintes tabelas:

- Sala1
- Sala2
- Sala3
- Sala4
- Sala5

Cada uma das tabelas têm as colunas:

- id (int/a_i)
- entrada (float) 8 até 21.5
- saida (float) 8.5 até 22
- status (int) 0 = livre | 1 = ocupado
- exibir_entrada (varchar) 08:00 até 21:30
- exibir_saida (varchar) 08:30 até 22:00

Tudo está bem, os registros são gravados em uma outra tabela com o nome _agenda_aulas_, a composição da tabela está assim:

- id (int/a_i)
- matricula_aluno (int null)
- nome_aluno (varchar)
- data (varchar)
- prof (varchar)
- entrada (varchar)
- saida (varchar)
- materia (varchar)
- qtd_hora (float)
- valor (float)
- pagamento (varchar)

A programação está funcionando, tanto para armazenar dos valores na tabela *agenda_aulas*, quanto para fazer update na tabela conforme a sala selecionada.

Trecho que faz a programação:

```
    //Pré Cadastro do aluno
    $QueryConsultarAlunos = "SELECT * FROM alunos WHERE matricula_aluno = '$matricula'";
    $ExeQrConsultarAlunos = mysql_query($QueryConsultarAlunos);
    if (!$ExeQrConsultarAlunos) {
        echo $QrPreCadastrarAluno = "INSERT INTO alunos (matricula_aluno,nome_aluno) VALUES ('$matricula','$nomeAluno')";
        $cadastrarAluno = mysql_query($QrPreCadastrarAluno, $db);
        echo '<br>';
    }

    echo $QrUpdateHorarioSalas = "UPDATE $salaDeAula SET status = 1 WHERE entrada = $horarioEntrada";
    mysql_query($QrUpdateHorarioSalas);
    echo "<br>";

    echo $QrCadastrar = "INSERT INTO agenda_aulas (matricula_aluno,nome_aluno,data,sala,prof,entrada,saida,materia,qtd_hora,valor,pagamento) VALUES ('$matricula','$nomeAluno','$dataAula', '$salaDeAula', '$professor', '$horarioEntrada', '$horarioSaida','$materiaAula','$tempoDeAula','$valorDaAula','$pagamentoAula')";
    $cadastrar = mysql_query($QrCadastrar, $db);
?>
```

Porém, como falei no começo, preciso destas mesmas informações de cada sala, mas com o filtro por dia.

Pensei em criar novas tabelas declarando como nome a data:

```
<?php
$tabelaDataAgendamento = 'ag_' . date('d_m_Y', strtotime($dataAula));
$resultAgData = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$tabelaDataAgendamento'");
$tabelaExists = mysql_num_rows($resultAgData) > 0;

if ($tabelaExists) {
    echo $QueryInserirTabelaData = "INSERT INTO '$tabelaDataAgendamento'(matricula_aluno,nome_aluno,sala,prof,entrada,saida,materia,qtd_hora,valor) VALUES('$matricula','$nomeAluno','$salaDeAula','$professor','$horarioEntrada','$horarioSaida','$materiaAula','$tempoDeAula','$valorDaAula')";
    $inserirTabelaData = mysql_query($QueryInserirTabelaData);
    echo "<br>";
    if ($inserirTabelaData):echo "Inserido!";
    else: echo "Não Inserido! Erro: " . mysql_error();
    endif;
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    echo $QueryCriarTabelaData = "CREATE TABLE `$tabelaDataAgendamento`(id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, matricula_aluno int, nome_aluno varchar(255),sala varchar(255),prof varchar(255),entrada float,saida float,materia varchar(255),qtd_hora float, valor float)ENGINE=INNODB;";
    mysql_query($QueryCriarTabelaData);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Só que o problema é, na hora de consultar os registros antes de inserir um novo registro, não sei como realizar o filtro.

Estou quebrando a cabeça para resolver isso já a quase uma semana, alguém pode me ajudar para solucionar este problema?

Agradeço antecipadamente a ajuda!

Comment: Não há como responder sem mais detalhes ou trechos de código.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá 
deixa eu ver se entendi, precisa filtras as 5 salas para ter a mesma informação com parâmetros diferentes na pesquisa por sala ?

Bom se for isso acredito que um union all das salas resolveria
Ex:
select id,data from tab1 where id=1
union
select id,data from tab2 where data <> 0;

Comment: Ajudou por parte, mas consegui resolver usando $_SESSION['DATA_INFORMADA'] e criando banco de dados por dia e tabelas com as salas para todos os dias.

Quando eu terminar a aplicação vou postar o link aqui pra ajudar quem precisar algum dia...

Mesmo assim, obrigado

Comment: ok, ótimo disponha!